# Query returning the query, not a result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

In my MVC app I want to get the name of the current restaurant that a user is creating a review for.

I created a simple Linq query to pull this out using the sent through restaurantId from the query string:

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(int restaurantId)
{
    var restuarantName = from r in _db.Restaurant
                         where r.Id == restaurantId
                         select r.Name;

    ViewBag.RestaurantName = restuarantName;

    return View();
}
```

However, the result that I get is:

```
"New Review for SELECT [EXTENT1].[NAME] AS [NAME] FROM [DBO].[RESTAURANT] AS [EXTENT1] WHERE [EXTENT1].[ID] = @P__LINQ__0".
```

Given the following in the view:

```
@ViewBag.RestaurantName
```

I checked the query in LinqPad and it successfully returns a name, why does this not seem to be executing?

**Restuarant Model**

```
public class Restaurant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Reviews> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

**DB Context**

```
public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurant { get; set; }
```

Comment: SingleOrDefault(), Single, First, FirstOrDefault..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`restuarantName` is of type `IQueryable`, meaning the query not *materialized* into data yet, in order to run it against the database, call:

`var restuarantName = _db.Restaurant.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id = restaurantId);`

Comment: Adding .Name to the end of the query gives just the name.

Comment: @jonnow ...and a possible `NullReferenceException`. `?.Name` might do the trick though.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ViewBag.RestaurantName = restuarantName.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the query to the view, the query is not being executed.
try something like

```
var restuarantName = _db.Restaurant(x => x.id = restaurantId).SingleOrDefault();
```

Assuming that you are looking for a single value